# Printing out specific name for a given random number; keeping a running total on the random numbers give

Tags: java

My program needs to print out 3 to 5 random numbers 10 times. It is about a skydiving problem in which the numbers 1-22 equal 1 point while 23-38 equal two points. I have created a program that has 10 different rounds with 5 random numbers in each round, but I can't seem to print out the formation related to a specific number i.e. if the one number equal 1 it will print out "Snowflake".

I have tried using if statements as a way to print out each of the formations but I keep getting an error saying that an int can't become a boolean.

```
 package skydiving;
 import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class SkyDiving{ 

public static void main(String[] args){
   int i = 1;
   SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();

 while (i<=10){

System.out.printf("Round %d",i++);
System.out.println("");
int totalPoints = 0;

for (int counter = 1 ; counter <= 5; counter++)
{
    int dive = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(38);

   if(dive == 1)
        System.out.println("1: Snowflake");
    else
    if(dive == 2)
        System.out.println("2: Sidebody Donut");
    else
     if(dive == 3)
        System.out.println("3: Side Flake Opal");   
    else
     if(dive == 4)
        System.out.println("4: Monopod");
    else
     if(dive == 5)
        System.out.println("5: Opal");
    else
     if(dive == 6)
        System.out.println("6: Stardian");
    else
     if(dive == 7)
        System.out.println("7: Sidebuddies");  
    else
     if(dive == 8)
        System.out.println("8: Canadian Tree");
    else
     if(dive == 9)
        System.out.println("9: Cat+Accoridan");
    else
     if(dive == 10 )
        System.out.println("10: Diamond");
    else
     if(dive == 11)
        System.out.println("11: Photon");
    else
     if(dive == 12 )
        System.out.println("12: Bundy");
    else
     if(dive == 13 )
        System.out.println("13: Offset");
    else
     if(dive == 14 )
        System.out.println("14: Bipole");
    else
     if(dive == 15)
        System.out.println("15: Caterpillar");
    else
     if(dive == 16)
        System.out.println("16: Compressed");
    else
     if(dive == 17 )
        System.out.println("17: Danish Tee");
    else
     if(dive == 18 )
        System.out.println("18: Zircon");
    else
     if(dive == 19 )
        System.out.println("19: Ritz");
    else
     if(dive ==20 )
        System.out.println("20: Piver");
    else
     if(dive == 21)
        System.out.println("21: Zig Zag");
    else
     if(dive == 22 )
        System.out.println("22: Tee");
    else
     if(dive == 23 )
        System.out.println("A:Unipod");
    else
     if(dive == 24 )
        System.out.println("B: Stairstep Diamond");
    else
     if(dive == 25 )
        System.out.println("C: Murphy Flake");
    else
     if(dive == 26 )
        System.out.println("D: Yuan");
    else
     if(dive == 27 )
        System.out.println("E: Meeker");
    else
     if(dive == 28)
        System.out.println("F: Open Accordian");
    else
     if(dive == 29 )
        System.out.println("G: Catacord");
    else
     if(dive == 30 )
        System.out.println("H: Bow");
    else
     if(dive == 31 )
        System.out.println("J: Donut");
    else
     if(dive == 32)
        System.out.println("K: Hook");
    else
     if(dive == 33 )
        System.out.println("L: Adder");
    else
     if(dive == 34 )
        System.out.println("M: Star");
    else
     if(dive == 35)
        System.out.println("N: Crank");
    else
     if(dive ==36 )
        System.out.println("O: Satelitte");
    else
     if(dive ==37 )
        System.out.println("P: Sidebody");
    else
     if(dive == 38 )
        System.out.println("Q: Phalanx");



   if(dive <= 22){
        totalPoints += 1;

    }
    else{
        totalPoints += 2;
    }     
 }    
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Total points: " + totalPoints);
   }     
  } 
 }
```

I've managed to get each number to print out a specific formation, it isn't pretty but she'll do. I can't seem to get the points to work, this is were it starts to get crazy. If three blocks are used (23-38) that is the only 6 point move. So I need to figure a way to stop the random numbers after 3 blocks are used. Basically there can only be two score 5 or 6, so I need to determine a way for the generator to keep shuffling until a suitable formation comes back out, if I have 4 random formations (1 pointers) I can't have a block (2 pointer) or it is an illegal formation.

Comment: Edit it into your question.  For the love of God, don't put it into the comment box.

Comment: Did his code get truncated?  The bottom half is missing.  There must be a code shark on the loose today on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The code fragment that you have put is incomplete. Still I would try to make it from the problem statement.

```
while (i<=10)
{
    System.out.printf("Round %d",i++);
    System.out.println("");
    int totalDives = 0;
    int totalPoints = 0;

    for (int counter = 1 ; counter <= 5; counter++)
    {
        int dive = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(38);
        totalDives += dive;        

        if(dive <= 22){
            totalPoints += 1;
            System.out.print("Snowflake");
        }
        else{
            totalPoints += 2;
            System.out.printf("%d ", dive);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("Total dives: " + totalDives);
System.out.println("Total points: " + totalPoints);
```

This calculates the total of dives, assigns points and then sums up the points.

**Update**

You can use a String array to store the dive texts. Then use it directly to print without the `if` statement

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 1;
    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    String[] diveStyles = {"1: Snowflake", "2: Sidebody Donut",
                      "3: Side Flake Opal", "4: Monopod", "5: Opal"}; // and so on

    while (i<=10){
        System.out.printf("Round %d",i++);
        System.out.println("");
        int totalPoints = 0;

        for (int counter = 1 ; counter <= 5; counter++)
        {
            int dive = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(38);

            System.out.println(diveStyles[dive-1]);

            if(dive <= 22){
                totalPoints += 1;
            }
            else{
                totalPoints += 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total points: " + totalPoints);
    }
}
```